# doxygen - namespace/scope name hide?

Tags: doxygen

My doxygen does great at linking C++ class names to my reference manual page. However, this only works if I also include the full namespace in front of the name. For example:

blah blah blah MyClass blah - no URL created for MyClass

blah blah blah MyNamespace::MyClass - URL is created for MyClass

I'm writing a programming guide with a lot of text and it is tedious to read the namespace in front of every class name. Is there a way to instruct doxygen to create the links even if the class name is not fully qualified with the namespace? Or simply remove the namespace when it is present? I have tried using HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES=YES in my config file, but there was no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you create your guide using `@page` type of commands and all classes are in `MyNamespace` you can simply put the comments containing `@page` inside the namespace, i.e.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
/** 
@page mypage My page

blah blah blah MyClass blah
*/
}
```

Then `MyClass` will link to `MyNamespace::MyClass` automatically.